# Finding a weighted average in Excel / Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying to calculate student marks using a weighted average like in this sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E35005CEgqYlkRYE3IIqVnWTaOROD54L3eEt4nIo-8Y/edit#gid=0

B4:B13 has the equation to do it but I will have about 40 assignments which would made this long to type out.

I tried using SUMPRODUCT but there are 2 problems:
 1. the weights are in every other column
 2. if the mark is a blank cell then the weight for that assignment should be zero. (ex. see student 10 where assignment 1 weight should be zero and the overall grade should be 100%.

How can i use a formula to achieve this?

Comment: if you want to exclude empty fields, just use something like `=(D13*$D$2/$D$1 + F13*$F$2/$F$1)*100/($D$2*(D13<>"")+$F$2*(F13<>""))` (will still calculate if there is a zero). the formula is for 
Student 10 but you can copy paste it to the other fields too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($D4:$Z4),2)=0)*(N(+D$1:$Z$1)<>0)*($D4:$Z4<>""),$D4:$Z4*$D$2:$Z$2/$D$1:$Z$1)*100/SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($D4:$Z4),2)=0)*(N(+D$1:$Z$1)<>0)*($D4:$Z4<>""),$D$2:$Z$2))))
```

[image]

If you want a formula that will grow with extra columns added then use this monster:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($D4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))),2)=0)*(N(+D$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2)))<>0)*($D4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))<>""),$D4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))*$D$2:INDEX($2:$2,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))/$D$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2)))*100/SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($D4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))),2)=0)*(N(+D$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2)))<>0)*($D4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))<>""),$D$2:INDEX($2:$2,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))))))
```

It will find the last column in which there is a number in row 2 and use that as its ending column.

Comment: The monster formula works!  However is there an easy way to change it if cells are moved?  I have adjusted my sheet to look like: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s8ZruF-YezGexpBo5C3cnFugv2WYcIoLUKzRvv7i9Bo/edit?usp=sharing (my fault for making changes)

Comment: @utphx just realized that I have enough other checks I do not need the MOD() so use this instead `=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF((N(+M$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2)))<>0)*($M4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))<>""),$M4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))*$M$2:INDEX($2:$2,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))/$M$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2)))*100/SUM(IF((N(+M$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2)))<>0)*($M4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))<>""),$M$2:INDEX($2:$2,MATCH(1E+99,$2:$2))))))`

Comment: I was able to modify your original monster code to: =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($N8:INDEX(8:8,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))),2)=0)*(N(+N$3:INDEX($3:$3,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4)))<>0)*($N8:INDEX(8:8,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))<>""),$N8:INDEX(8:8,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))*$N$4:INDEX($4:$4,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))/$N$3:INDEX($3:$3,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4)))*100/SUM(IF((MOD(COLUMN($N8:INDEX(8:8,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))),2)=0)*(N(+N$3:INDEX($3:$3,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4)))<>0)*($N8:INDEX(8:8,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))<>""),$N$4:INDEX($4:$4,MATCH(1E+99,$4:$4))))))  and it works well, thanks!